# How to create a function from string (Python3)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input

Good day everyone.

My program shold take commands by `stdin` in a particular format, like:

```
"define f1 3 + 5"
```

By getting this command, my program should create a function named "f1", which will return the action "3+5".

How can I realise it?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write a parser, you should be able to find plenty examples online of parsers written in python.  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Did you try `python -i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dictionary to store a function with a given name. In general, you should not create a function name from a string.

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to safely evaluate a computation provided as a string.

Here is one example:

```
from ast import literal_eval

mystr = input('Enter a calculation:\n')
# 'define f1 3 + 5'

_, name, calc = mystr.split(None, 2)

d = {name: literal_eval(calc)}

print(d['f1'])  # 8
```